# Dagger2 Minimum Dependencies

Tags: android, dagger-2

Which of the following are the required minimum dependencies for setting up Dagger2?

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'

annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'

implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.14.1'

annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14.1'

implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.14.1'

provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'

annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
```

You can get away with the above just fine but if you want to use the recently introduced [dagger.android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) you'll at least need these two as well.

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.14.1'

annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14.1'
```

I believe the the `dagger-android-suppprt` is just if you're using `DaggerAppCompatActivity`, `DaggerFragments`, etc like in the [Todo-MVP-Dagger Android Architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger) example.

I don't think you need the last one at all, I don't have that in any my projects that use Dagger.